# Into which category does the phrase "middle end" fall?

Tags: compounds, errors

In compiler design, you can sometimes read the phrase [middle end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Three_phases_compiler_structure).
In that context "front end" and "back end" are natural combinations, where "end" denotes the position in the chain and "back/front" denote the logical position in the process. "Middle end", however seems paradox: Although it clearly lies in the middle of the process, it is definitely not any end of the chain. Even worse, the prefix "middle" seems to automatically contradict its suffix.

My theory is, that the term was later added, when "front end" and "back end" where already established for some simpler designs. Is that plausible? Is my conception of "middle end" being self-contradictory true? If so, is there a name for such combinations in the english language?

Comment: If there's a good but hidden reason why 'middle end' makes sense, the concisely-stated paradox would be called an 'oxymoron'. If it's just a compound noun that someone came up with, patterning on the other two, it's a 'misnomer': on analysis,a contradiction in terms, but acceptable idiomatically.

Comment: Thanks. Why not make this an answer?

Comment: Oxymorons, contradictions in terms, misnomers, and (Probably by far the most important on a site like ELU) many aspects of compound nouns have all been addressed in previous questions.

Comment: From reading the bit at wikipedia it looks like "middle-end" is being added to make compilers capable of being cross-platform. That's obviously a later consideration in the development of computer science, so your assumption that "middle-end" is a term created later and modeled off of the more logical terms front-end and back-end sounds correct to me.

Comment: Phrases like this are common in computer technology. We frequently adopt words and phrases from other contexts as metaphors, and then we modify them for related concepts. The modified forms are often phrases that make no sense literally, they should just be considered idioms.